# Android httpurlconnection upload file with progress

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-progressbar

I'm very new in Android, I apologize if this question is duplicate, but I've been trying to find a working and complete httpurlconnection function that supports progress, I can only find snippets here and there and none of the ones I found worked.

Anyone here knows working library or merely a function that uses httpurlconnection that supports uploading file with progress?

Please note that I got the thread part.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably use Android's [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for http connections. In android, you can't do network stuff on the main thread, so we use the asynctask class, which spawns a background thread. It's also capable of showing progress at various stages.

For the progress bar specifically, look at asynctask's onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) function

Comment: Thanks, but this has nothing to do with the question, as I mentioned "Please note that I got the thread part.". I'm looking for the implementation of the uploading with progress function regardless of the main UI thread vs threading argument.

Comment: Are you using asynctask already or are you doing the threading and connecting yourself, or are you using a third-party library?

Comment: Yes, I am using Asynctask, again, I'm looking for the httpurlconnection with progress part, not httpurlconnection with HTTP upload any.

Comment: You try using the onProgressUpdate within the background task thread? That allows you to post updates to something in the main thread, like a progress dialog. Perhaps I am still midunderstanding.


Personally, I use a third party library called [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion). It does a lot of that stuff for you, so you can just do something like [this](https://github.com/koush/ion#download-a-file-with-a-progress-bar).